# MYSQL select query giving duplicated listing

Tags: php, mysql

I need some help with this query. I have 2 tables of data

Booking table

| bookingid | booking_date | booking_start | staffid | studentid | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-10-10 | 7.30pm | 1 | 12345678 | ended |
| 2 | 2021-10-10 | 11.30am | 1 | 12345679 | ended |
| 3 | 2021-10-10 | 12.00pm | 1 | NULL | cancelled |

Student table
|studentid|firstname|lastname|
|--|--|--|
|12345678|john|doe|
|12345679|mary|doe|
|12345670|vincent|doe|

What table im looking for

| booking_date | booking_start | studentname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10-10 | 7.30pm | john doe |
| 2021-10-10 | 11.30pm | mary joe |
| 2021-10-10 | 12.00pm | NULL |

Using this query,

```
Select Booking_date, 
       Booking_start, 
       case WHEN booking.StudentID is NULL THEN NULL ELSE student.First_name end as First_name, 
       case WHEN booking.StudentID is NULL THEN NULL ELSE student.Last_name end as Last_name, 
       BookingID 
from booking, student 
where (booking.staffid = '$userid') ORDER BY booking_start ASC)
```

This is the table i am getting

| booking_date | booking_start | studentname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10-10 | 7.30pm | john doe |
| 2021-10-10 | 7.30pm | mary doe |
| 2021-10-10 | 7.30pm | vincent doe |
| 2021-10-10 | 11.30pm | mary joe |
| 2021-10-10 | 11.30pm | john joe |
| 2021-10-10 | 11.30pm | vincent joe |
| 2021-10-10 | 12.00pm |  |
| 2021-10-10 | 12.00pm |  |

There should be 1 more 2021-10-10|12.00pm|| im unable to show it due to formatting issues.
It shows duplicated listing with the wrong student name.
What can I do to fix this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join tables like this :

```
booking inner join student on booking.StudentID = student.StudentID
```

---

```
    Select Booking_date,
       Booking_start,
       student.First_name,      
       student.Last_name,
       BookingID
  from booking inner join student on booking.StudentID = student.StudentID
 where (booking.staffid = '$userid')
 ORDER BY booking_start ASC
```

if you dont join tables, they act like cartesian joins, all rows are matched with all others, so it generates duplicate . for example , if you have 2 table with 10 rows each, in result you get 10*10 result ...

Inner join  = you get only if records are matched.

If you have records on booking table and it has no studing_id matched with students table , and still want to display it as a result, you need to use **LEFT JOIN** instead of **INNER JOIN**

Also its the best to use join syntax instead of old joins like :

old syntax :

```
student,booking 
where 
student.id = booking.studentid
```

new syntax:

```
student inner join booking on student.id = booking.studentid
```

Comment: Ah thanks, I was having issues with using join as it gave the same result, looks like i was missing a condition.

Comment: note the 3rd row in expected result, `LEFT JOIN` to get the result. And `CASE WHEN` is redundant

Comment: ah yes let me fix it for others

Comment: thanks for the edit, yes i need to display null for studentid, firstname. lastname. Therefore i think left join with case when is more proper.